# Custom Action for Install first & not reinstall for higher versions

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-installer

I am trying to execute a condition statement when a file is not present, or if present then not to modify it. I have used Installed, NOT Installed but doesn't work for me.

Kindly help me through this or let me know if I am missing something here.

Comment: What type of file is this? Can you remove the whole file installed and install a read-only template file somewhere else - that you never touch - but that you copy to the file that needs to be writable? This will de-couple the settings file from deployment interference (largely - there are some issues on uinstall for example). You need to update your application to do this work, and that is a familiar debugging context. Much easier and same source as application (good for QA purposes too).

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Actually the scenario is users have an old application and that contains a server.exe (previous version). But In my new installer, the same server.exe consists of the new version but the point is I do not want to replace/modify or reinstall the new server.exe but if it doesn't present on the old application then my newly server.exe will install there. I hope this clarifies you